# Mapping a list while using a dictionary?

Tags: swift, function, dictionary

I can't seem to understand how it results in ["***OneSix***", "FiveEight", "FiveOneZero"]. The way I see it is that it maps through the list and the % sign evaluates the number to "Six" first. So why does "One" come before "Six" in the results?

This part confuses me:

> ```
> output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
>     number /= 10
> ```

```
let digitNames = [
0: "Zero", 1: "One", 2: "Two",   3: "Three", 4: "Four",
5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine"
]

let numbers = [16, 58, 510]


let strings = numbers.map {
(number) -> String in
var number = number
var output = ""
while number > 0 {
    output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
    number /= 10
}
return output
}
// strings is inferred to be of type [String]
// its value is ["OneSix", "FiveEight", "FiveOneZero"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to see how a loop works is to work through it one step at a time with a pencil and paper.

Let's say the number is `123`. Then the loop would work like this:

```
var output = ""
while number > 0 {
    output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
    number /= 10
}
```

- Before the initial iteration `output=""` and `number=123`
- After the first iteration `output` becomes `"Three"` and `number becomes`12`
- After the second iteration `output` becomes `"TwoThree"` and number becomes `1`
- After the last iteration `output` becomes `"OneTwoThree"` and number becomes `0`

In other words, the `output` is growing from back to front, but at the same time the `number` "shrinks" from back to front, too, so the correct order is maintained through the process.

Comment: Oh, that's right! It's basically iterating to make it print the tens and hundreds places of a number into string form. Sweet thanks!